# Is it possible to create a recurring task in OpenProj?

Tags: pm-software, tasks, open-source

Is it possible to create a recurring task in OpenProj? If so, how do you edit a task to make it a recurring task?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, OpenProj is a fantastic resource but does lack a few nice features. No recurring tasks in ProjectLibre either I'm afraid - no resource pool either I think.

To get around the issues we eventually got MSProj on one pm machine. Other resources use openproj and export to project xml. The PM then compiles into MS Proj to get everthing into the resource pool, add recurring tasks, etc. A bit messy, but works for us.

Comment: Edit: just noticed this was an old post. Must have had an odd sort order on my view as it was the first question.

Comment: Hi @Trev. Welcome to PMSE. No problem answering old posts (especially if they haven't been answered!)

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search indicates that you're not the only one with this problem. It appears that OpenProj has changed owners and subsequently been replaced by [project libre](http://www.projectlibre.org/). I don't have access to Project Libre, but someone claiming to be one of the authors claims that the new software will include recurring tasks.